# Java regex to match a pattern

Tags: java, regex

I am new to Java. Please help me with a Java regex to match a pattern and retrieve the value.
I need to match the pattern bellow:

```
\# someproperty=somevalue // this is a new property

\#someproperty=somevalue // this is a new property
```

I have to match the above patterns (which may contains spaces) and I need to retrieve `"someproperty"` and `"somevalue"`.

I tried with the pattern below, but it just matches only `someproperty=somevalue` , without `"#"` at the beginning. Please help me out.

```
Pattern propertyKeyPattern = Pattern.compile("^\\s*(\\S+?)\\s*=.*?");
```

Comment: Remove the `^` or add a `#` after it.

Comment: Is `# this is a new property` a part of string? Or a comment?

Comment: You don't need a reluctant matching at the end. Just remove `?` and add `$` to it. BTW, if you are using `Matcher.matches`, then the anchors are implicit, you don't need to put them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to match the whole string and find patterns, such as "`\#  someproperty  =some value`".
Try regular Expression

```
^\\#\s*(\S+?)\s*=(.*)$
```

as Java string, it is

```
"^\\\\#\\s*(\\S+?)\\s*=(.*)$"
```

The match result for string `\# someproperty = a some value` is

```
matches() = Yes

find()    = Yes

group(0)  = \# someproperty = a some value

group(1)  = someproperty

group(2)  = a some value
```

Answer (score 0):

String a=yourString.replaceAll("[^\w\s]"," ");
By using this you will get "someproperty" and "somevalue" string then u can check it. For more post your question clearly.