# Pattern matching to fetch a value

Tags: java, pattern-matching

Suppose I have a String, called text, which contains the following :

```
blabla="A_VALUE"
```

Is it possible, with pattern matching, to directly retrieve the value inside the quotation marks?

For example : something similar to Format String, where you could write a pattern, %s, and then get that value.

Right now, a workaround I found is :

```
text = text.replace("blabla=","");
text = text.replaceAll("\"","");
```

However, this is very ugly.

**Note : It doesn't have to be java, I want to know if the concept exists, and if so, what name does it have.**

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13578326/java-regex-to-match-a-pattern?rq=1) offers some insight, although I'm unsure what `\\\\#\\s*(\\S+?)\\s*` is suppose to mean

Comment: To be clear, are you trying to retrieve `A_VALUE` from the `String`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8430022/what-is-the-java-equivalent-of-sscanf-for-parsing-values-from-a-string-using-a-k

Answer (score 1):

In [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) there is `sscanf` which is similar to what you described.

However Java has a Scanner class instead of such a function.

Another alternative is to use Regular Expressions then inspect the relevant Matcher group, as described here: [what is the Java equivalent of sscanf for parsing values from a string using a known pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8430022/what-is-the-java-equivalent-of-sscanf-for-parsing-values-from-a-string-using-a-k)

Comment: Interesting link. I used pattern and regex somewhere else but would get match.start and then struggle to format the match.end to remove unwanted characters. Let's suppose my pattern here is "blabla=", then I still need to do some work afterwards to get the actual value. 

I was missing the 'group' keyword, which looks like it allows you to fetch the data inside the pattern. Useful link I found : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16517689/confused-about-matcher-group-in-java-regex

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean get the content of strings including any escaped double-quotes?

If so, then this pattern should work for you: `"(\\.|[^"])*"`

It means: find a double quote then find zero or more occurrences of any escaped character or anything that's not a double-quote until another quote is found.

Broken down:

- `"` - find a double quote
- `\\.` - find any escaped character
- `[^"]` - find any character that's not a double quote
- `(x|y)*` - find x or y zero or more times
- `(\\.|[^"])*` - find any escaped char or any non-double-quote character zero or more times.

It will find:

```
Source                        Result
----------------------------+---------------
var str1 = "a string";      | "a string"
var str2 = "a \" string"    | "a \" string"
var str3 = "";              | ""
var str4 = "a string \\";   | "a string \\"
```

Comment: won't this fail if you have an escaped backslash as the last character?

Comment: addendum to my previous comment: And there are more quoted string later in the input.

Comment: @PatrickParker Yes, good call. I've made an edit correcting this.

Comment: This line text = text.replaceAll("\"",""); shows that I'm actually removing the quotation marks. Which is why I was stucked using pattern matching since what I need to find is simply a String.

Your technic would however work, given that I remove the " afterwards in my answer!

Comment: @Maude yes, it could be easily stripped off afterwards. Or, rather than matching a quotemark, instead you could match the zero-width position after/before a quotemark, using the positive lookbehind/lookahead regexp syntax.